# Why do I encounter: "TypeError: t(...).isPlaceholder is not a function" when "import './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'"

Tags: reactjs

I installed bootstrap via `npm install` already and  i tried to import it to my App.js file:

```
import './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

But then the app return this on the browser:

> TypeError: t(...).isPlaceholder is not a function
>   Could someone please explain why and how to fix?
>   Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For me, I saw these errors when I bumped `@babel` dependencies a few minor versions (several packages and plugins).
What helped was removing the `node_modules` directory and then installing all the packages again.

1. Remove node_modules: `rm -rf ./node_modules`
2. Install packages `yarn` or `npm i`
3. Run your project again

Comment: I've been having this issue consistently for weeks every time package.json gets edited (which happens every time I switch branches, since we have a linked project).  Removing `node_modules` is the only solution I've found (and sometimes it takes 2-3 tries, which is ridiculous).  It _must_ be a `yarn` bug, right?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error.

To fix it, make sure you're not mixing up your package managers. I was using yarn, but then used npm because that's what we use at work.

> you should add or install your modules using the same package manager

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with a standard create-react-app structure via:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, it's a `yarn` bug related to using `yarn link` with a messy lockfile.  The solution was to use [`yarn-deduplicate`](https://github.com/atlassian/yarn-deduplicate).

---

Prior to finding that fix, my workaround was

1. `yarn link other-repo` from main-repo
2. `yarn install` from main-repo
3. `yarn install --check-files` from other-repo

Which can be done using an `alias`